# What is the total number of dismembered limbs in the Star Wars films?

Tags: star-wars

I'm surprised this hasn't been asked yet. 
Having just seen *Rogue One* and rewatched *A New Hope*, dismemberments are exceedingly common.   If go far as to say they are a recurring theme.

For the purpose of this question, dismemberment includes any full or partial removal of an arm or leg,  wherein the limb is fairly intact and the victim survives.   That includes assaults to biological beings,  cyborgs,  and droids, and dismemberment by severing (e.g. lightsaber) or raw force (e.g. Wookiee).

Comment: No @Praxis, **this** question is a Popmachinism

Comment: Straw poll:  should I make this community wiki?

Comment: @Adamant, fair enough-- I couldn't find it.

Comment: The question is too localized, because the answer is going to change every time they make another damn Star Wars movie.

Comment: @user14111, that is not the way too localized works.   Otherwise you could never ask a question about a series that is still actively being produced.   If you don't believe me,  take it to meta,  or perhaps one of the  great sages will like an appropriate meta here.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : True, but apparently I beat you to it by a year!